# Connection error with latest odbc driver: set_err: state ('H') is not a 5 character string, using 'S1000' instead

Tags: google-bigquery, odbc

I've returned to a previously working project, updated the BigQuery ODBC drivers, and tried to connect, and I'm getting:

> set_err: state ('H') is not a 5 character string, using 'S1000' instead

Any ideas what's causing this error?

I'm using a service account, and have downloaded a pk12 key and placed it in my DSN-less connection string:

```
DRIVER=BigQuery;OAuthMechanism=0;Email=bigquery-service-account@api-project-438416064020.iam.gserviceaccount.com;KeyFilePath=/opt/BigQuery/api-project-438416064020-bf17df0b92a5.p12;Catalog=bigquery-public-data;UseNativeQuery=1;SQLDialect=1
```

I then looked in [guide](https://www.simba.com/products/BigQuery/doc/ODBC_InstallGuide/linux/content/odbc/bq/strings.htm) and trimmed out what appeared to be optional/deprecated key/value pairs, to arrive at the connection string:

```
DRIVER=BigQuery;OAuthMechanism=0;Email=bigquery-service-account@api-project-438416064020.iam.gserviceaccount.com;KeyFilePath=/opt/BigQuery/api-project-438416064020-bf17df0b92a5.p12;Catalog=bigquery-public-data
```

This gives me the same error. So I turned on logging in simba.googlebigqueryodbc.ini and tried again, and found:

> Nov 11 15:47:28.922 TRACE 3381425984 RESTAction::RESTAction: +++++ enter +++++
>   Nov 11 15:47:28.922 TRACE 3381425984 RESTAction::Reset: +++++ enter +++++
>   Nov 11 15:47:28.922 DEBUG 3381425984 GExponentialBackoff::GExponentialBackoff: StartTime: 1489618586
>   Nov 11 15:47:28.922 TRACE 3381425984 BigQueryAPIClient::BigQueryAPIClient: +++++ enter +++++
>   Nov 11 15:47:28.922 TRACE 3381425984 GSqlDataFactory::GSqlDataFactory: +++++ enter +++++
>   Nov 11 15:47:28.922 TRACE 3381425984 GConnection::GConnection: +++++ enter +++++
>   Nov 11 15:47:28.922 TRACE 3381425984 GConnection::SetConnectionPropertyValues: +++++ enter +++++
>   Nov 11 15:47:28.922 TRACE 3381425984 Connection::SQLSetConnectAttr: +++++ enter +++++
>   Nov 11 15:47:28.922 INFO  3381425984 Connection::SQLSetConnectAttr: Attribute: SQL_ATTR_ANSI_APP (115)
>   Nov 11 15:47:28.922 TRACE 3381425984 ConnectionState::SQLSetConnectAttr: +++++ enter +++++
>   Nov 11 15:47:28.922 TRACE 3381425984 ConnectionAttributes::SetAttribute: +++++ enter +++++
>   Nov 11 15:47:28.922 TRACE 3381425984 Connection::SQLDriverConnectW: +++++ enter +++++
>   Nov 11 15:47:28.922 TRACE 3381425984 ConnectionState2::SQLDriverConnectW: +++++ enter +++++
>   Nov 11 15:47:28.924 ERROR 3381425984 Connection::SQLDriverConnectW: [Simba][Support] (50404) Invalid connection string.`

But it doesn't say which part is invalid :(

> set_err: state ('H') is not a 5 character string, using 'S1000' instead

Comment: Do you get the same error if you set the connection string exactly as the guide mentions? `Driver=Simba ODBC Driver for Google BigQuery;
OAuthMechanism=0;Email=bigquery-service-account@api-project-438416064020.iam.gserviceaccount.com;KeyFilePath=/opt/BigQuery/api-project-438416064020-bf17df0b92a5.p12;Catalog=bigquery-public-data;`

Comment: Also, which version of the Driver are you using?

Comment: Hi ch_mike - thanks for the reply. My driver string *is* in exactly the same form, except for the driver name ( which is dynamically generated by our app, which also manages ~/odbcinst.ini ). Just in case something strange was going on ( eg hard-coded driver name inside the driver, required for some unknown reasons ), I've hard-coded it to the entire string "Simba ODBC Driver for Google BigQuery" ... and yes, I still get the same error.

I'm using: SimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery64_2.2.2.1007 - which was the latest I found when I checked a couple of days back.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I did a fair amount of research on your issue, but I haven't been able to make much progress, my recommendation at this point is to open an [Issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#search_for_or_create_issues_and_feature_requests_by_product) for the GCP/Simba teams to troubleshoot this. You can do so using [this form](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162659)

Comment: Hi ch_mike. Thanks for the advice. I've raised a ticket: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144442750